# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyexiv2/lib/libexiv2.so) colab goo

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, pyexiv2

I tried to read the metadata of an image in google colab  but I got an error of GLIBC_2.29 not found .
Here is my script :

```
    import pyexiv2
    m1 = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata( '/content/H0002.png' )
    m1.read()
```

the error :

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyexiv2/lib/libexiv2.so)
```

Comment: There is [a relevant issue on the repo of pyexiv2](https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2/issues/73).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have to recompile a libc. The problem is that the version of libc is low. If it is not necessary, it is recommended not to compile libc and soft link because libc is the underlying library of the system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).